# Ansible Template to push to multiple host

Tags: templates, ansible

I have host names mentioned in Inventory file

```
[PROD_NEW]
PROD_NEW-31 ansible_ssh_host=xx.xx.xx.xx ansible_ssh_pass=abcdefg ansible_ssh_user=root somename=PROD_NEW31
PROD_NEW-32 ansible_ssh_host=xx.xx.xx.xx ansible_ssh_pass=abcdefg ansible_ssh_user=root somename=PROD_NEW32
```

And in roles template directory i have a below script

{{ansible_ssh_host}}_tag.sh

```
export SERVER_TAG={{somename}}
```

how can i push this export variable to all host in my inventory with script file name {{ansible_ssh_host}}

I treid below answer but getting error

```
The error appears to have been in '/opt/SP/users/tooladm/GSS/Pre-Checks/pushtags/tasks/main.yml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
       src: script_tag.sh.j2
       dest: /opt/SP/{{ item }}_tag.sh
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

exception type: <class 'yaml.parser.ParserError'>
exception: while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 6
did not find expected key
  in "<unicode string>", line 6, column 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template in `templates/script_tag.sh.j2`

```sh
export SERVER_TAG={{ somename }}
```

Your playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: PROD_NEW
  tasks:
    - name: push my template file to hosts in play
      template:
        src: script_tag.sh.j2
        dest: "/some/path/on/host/{{ ansible_ssh_host }}_tag.sh"
```

And then simply run your playbook using your inventory:

```
ansible-playbook -i your_inventory.ini your_playbook.yml
```

Comment: thanks for Suggestion but how do i poullate that {{ somename }} using inventory file ?

Comment: I simply used the identifier you already have in your current inventory for each host. I added a launch example.

Comment: yes i tried it but if you see i updated query with new error

Comment: Your task is obviously using a loop and is inside a much more general playbook/role than the only task I gave as an example. The problem is somewhere in the interpreted files and there is no way to know where with just your output.